# Magento reindexing keeps generating .lock files

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex

In the Magento backend all reindexing processes are done -> status ready. Green buttons for all the indexes.

In the FTP when I delete the lock files in the directory `var/locks/` they are deleted and re-created instantly. And the last edited time of the `.lock` files changes every second. While there is no index process running when I check it in the backend. So I delete `.lock` file and in 1 second it re-appears.

I have tried deleting the complete `var/locks` folder but when I recreate it the lock files appear instantly. Also I tried restarting apache. I tried renaming `indexer.php` but even then the lock files were re-created again.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have an instance of Magento 1.9 that keeps generating index_process_4.lock and index_process_5.lock, and it is causing issues. Thanks for any in-site.

Answer (score 2):

I think Magento handles these by itself. So unless you are having a problem with it existing I suggest leaving them there.

Remember indexing will happen through cron jobs so your probably seeing the result of the index running creating it while it works and exiting without actually needing to do anything.